# Removing files using Git GUI

Tags: git, git-gui

Is there any way to remove a file using git gui then commit and push?

Comment: *Git Extensions* can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942091/remove-file-from-git-using-git-extension-gui-tool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly, since [`git gui`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html) is more about:

> allowing users to make changes to their repository by making new commits, amending existing ones, creating branches, performing local merges, and fetching/pushing to remote repositories

An extension like [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/FAQ#How_to_remove_file_from_version_control_and_keep_local_copy) would allow a `git rm` to be performed graphically.

Comment: Nice touch adding the Tortoise GIT mention.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You could also just delete the file and *then* stage that to be committed in `git gui`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Click on the Web IDE option on the commit information panel, this would ideally take you to the editor panel with the repo structure listed on the left blade.

Step 2. Click on the directory you wish to delete and commit the new changes and merge with the other branches if required.