# Remove file from git using Git-Extension GUI tool

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am using the latest verion of Git-extensions on Windows 10.

I would like to remove an already check in file from my git repo without deleting it locally.

I can not some to find out how to do this.

I have tried right clicking on it in the diff view, but no option is provided to remove.

In the commit view, there is a "delete" option. I have not tried that, because I am not sure if it will delete the local copy. Is this Commit view -> Delete option essentially a remove?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: Since then, I have added this option in GitExtensions. You could achieve that by selecting the menu item "Stop tracking this file" in 2 different places :

- in the contextual menu in the commit form if the file has changed,
- in the contextual menu of the file tree when you select a commit in the revision grid.

---

There is no way to do it, as I remember. 
But there is a really easy way to achieve that by tricking GitExtensions.

Just do:

- rename the file
- stage and commit just the 'delete' change on the file
- rename the file to its original name

But that could easily be done with the command line by doing `git rm --cached the_file.ext`